# How to set up well UIScrollView

Tags: swift

I'm trying to set up a UIScrollView but it's not working. It could be my constraints but I'm not sure. Furthermore, I would like to ask if my code is well or not really. I'm learning Swift from scratch, so any advice is good to take.

Here's my code

```swift
//  SecondeMenu.swift
//  Bot Tes Maths
//
//  Created by lucas abijmil on 23/09/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 Lucas Abijmil. All rights reserved.
//
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class SecondeMenu: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // Hide or not the Navigation Bar
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set Up the NavBar
        setUpNavigationBar(button: backButton)

        // Set Up the container for ChoixChapitre
        setUpContainer(container: containerChoixChapitre, backgoundCo: .red, autoresizing: false)
        containerChoixChapitreLabelAutoLayout()

        // Set up Choix Chapitre
        setUpLabelString(label: choixChapitre, text: "Choix du chapitre", textA: .center, alpha: 1, backgoundCo: .clear, autoresizing: false)
        choixChapitreIntoContainer()

        // Set Up Scrolling
        setUpScroolView(scrooling: scrolling, autoresizing: false)
        scrollingDemarcation()

    }

// Declaration of our variable :

    // Declaration for the backButton of the BarNavigation
    private let backButton = UIBarButtonItem()

    // Declaration of UIView for contain
    private let containerChoixChapitre = UIView()
    let test = UIView()

    // Declaration of Variables for Seconde Menu (basically the name of each chapter
    private let choixChapitre = UILabel()
    private let scrolling = UIScrollView()
    private let choixChapitreStack = UIStackView()
    private let nombreReel = UILabel()
    private let nombreIrationnel = UILabel()
//    private let nombreReel = UILabel()


// Some functions incoming... ‍ (when i'm coding)

    // Set up scroolView
    private func setUpScroolView (scrooling : UIScrollView, autoresizing : Bool) {
        scrooling.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = autoresizing
        view.addSubview(scrooling)
    }

    // Set up container
    private func setUpContainer (container : UIView, backgoundCo : UIColor, autoresizing : Bool) {
          container.backgroundColor = backgoundCo
          container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = autoresizing
          view.addSubview(container)
    }

    // Set up NavigationBar
    private func setUpNavigationBar (button : UIBarButtonItem) {
        // title navigation bar
        self.navigationItem.title = "Menu Seconde"

        // back button set tittle
        button.title = "Retour"

        // Connect the button to the navigationBar
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = button

    }

    // Set Up Label
    private func setUpLabelString (label : UILabel, text : String, textA : NSTextAlignment, alpha : CGFloat, backgoundCo : UIColor, autoresizing : Bool) {
        label.text = text
        label.textAlignment = textA
        label.alpha = alpha
        label.backgroundColor = backgoundCo
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = autoresizing
    }

    private func setUpChapitreStack (stack : UIStackView, axe : NSLayoutConstraint.Axis, space : CGFloat, autoresizing : Bool) {
        stack.axis = axe
        stack.spacing = space
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = autoresizing
    }

    private func setUpLabelForStack (label : UILabel, text : String, textA : NSTextAlignment, alpha : CGFloat, backgroundCo : UIColor) {
        label.text = text
        label.textAlignment = textA
        label.alpha = alpha
        label.backgroundColor = backgroundCo
    }


// Sizing and contraints :

    // Sizing the scrolling dermarcation
    private func scrollingDemarcation() {
        scrolling.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerChoixChapitre.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        scrolling.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo : view.bottomAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
        scrolling.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrolling.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrolling.backgroundColor = .purple
//        scrolling.addSubview(choixChapitreStack)
    }

    // Sizing the container for choixLabel
    private func containerChoixChapitreLabelAutoLayout() {
        containerChoixChapitre.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        containerChoixChapitre.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        containerChoixChapitre.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        containerChoixChapitre.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }


// Add to the scene
    // Add "Choix du chapitre"
    private func choixChapitreIntoContainer() {
        containerChoixChapitre.addSubview(choixChapitre)
        choixChapitre.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerChoixChapitre.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        choixChapitre.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerChoixChapitre.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant : 0).isActive = true
    }

}
```

For the moment, I can't scroll, but I should be able to.

Thanks for your help .

Comment: https://medium.com/@evanhughes3/creating-a-uiscrollview-without-using-interface-builder-434dfac1a320 Good article to read

Answer (score 0):

First, change the flow in ViewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set Up the NavBar
        setUpNavigationBar(button: backButton)

       // Set Up Scrolling
        setUpScroolView(scrooling: scrolling, autoresizing: false)
        scrollingDemarcation()

        // Set Up the container for ChoixChapitre
        setUpContainer(container: containerChoixChapitre, backgoundCo: .red, autoresizing: false)
        containerChoixChapitreLabelAutoLayout()

        // Set up Choix Chapitre
        setUpLabelString(label: choixChapitre, text: "Choix du chapitre", textA: .center, alpha: 1, backgoundCo: .clear, autoresizing: false)
        choixChapitreIntoContainer()

    }
```

And for adding the container view to scroll view

```
// Set up container
private func setUpContainer (container : UIView, backgoundCo : UIColor, autoresizing : Bool) {
      container.backgroundColor = backgoundCo
      container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = autoresizing
      self.scrolling.addSubview(container)
}
```

Hope this will work.